# Проблема с GET запросом к API

Tags: reactjs, api, async-await, fetch, openweathermap

При отправке GET запроса на сервер OpenWeatherMap не могу получить ответ (даже 401 ошибки нет). Ключ присутствует, запрос делаю вроде бы правильно, ниже есть вариант который pending выдает, но с этим понятно. Даже со статичными данными ничего не происходит. (даже если в конце запроса написать `lang=ru` ничего не меняется)

Вот код:

```
import './App.css';
import {useEffect} from "react";

function App() {
    const getWeather = async (city) => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=29a0346ff342913fb597eb400c44f143`)
        return await response.json()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const getCurrentWeather = async () => {
            const weather = await getWeather('Moscow')
            await console.log(weather)
            console.log(weather)
        }
        getCurrentWeather()
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>test</div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   function App() {
const [weather, setWeather] = useState({})
const getWeather = async (city) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=29a0346ff342913fb597eb400c44f143`)
    return await response.json()
}

const getCurrentWeather = () => {
    getWeather('Moscow')
        .then(data => {
            setWeather(data)
        })
}
if (weather) {
    console.log(weather)
}

useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentWeather()
}, [])
return (
    <div>test</div>
);
}
```

так?